# In AWS, Can we use only one customer managed key to two different dynamodb table? Is it good practice?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kms

```
DynamoDbTableKmsKey:
    Type: AWS::KMS::Key

Table1:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      SSESpecification:
        SSEEnabled: True
        SSEType: KMS
        KMSMasterKeyId: !Ref DynamoDbTableKmsKey

Table2:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      SSESpecification:
        SSEEnabled: True
        SSEType: KMS
        KMSMasterKeyId: !Ref DynamoDbTableKmsKey
```

I've been looking on the aws documentation but I cannot see if it is not a good idea or a good practice or if it is possible.

Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, you can. Nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the same key for multiple tables, and there is nothing wrong with doing so as you can define a fine grained policy on the key which can limit the access to each table independently.